# HTML add songs to playlist and play songs on browser

Tags: html, browser, xhtml, dhtml, playlist

I've basic HTML programming knowledge, I'm working in a web-based environment for system administration. I want to make a html or any other code to play songs on the browser one after the other(something like having an option to add to playlist) on ubuntu. I copied the songs to apache root(/var/www/songs) and it's playing which ever song is selected(http://localhost/songs). I'm thinking if it is possible to list all the songs and  to create a playlist with html so that I can add songs to be played next on the browser with some apache virtualhosting.

Anybody has any script to list songs directory and play songs continuously one after the other adding songs to playlist on the browser?.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the open-source library called Opentape:
http://opentape.fm/

It allows you to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. You saved me especially in up-voting my question as it was down voted twice. I'll give a try and come back here. Thank you!

Comment: I checked it, it's good but could not upload the directory which has many songs in GB

Comment: Why not? What happens when the directory is too big?

Comment: It says opentape only takes mp3 formats. I am sure all are mp3

Comment: opentape is not much in it but programmers can do a better format with graphics to list directories and subdirectories with play list options. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com/example/playlist.m3u"  autostart="true"  type="audio/mpeg" loop="true"/>
```